# Is our hosting provider lying to me?

Tags: elasticsearch, optimization, memory, speedoptimization, website-speed

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Porto theme
Amasty extensions
```

I have a VPS Cloud4 account ($140/month) with the following specifications:

```
6 x 2.50 GHz Cores
16 GB ECC RAM
320 GB SSD Space
8 TB Bandwidth
cPanel/WHM/Softaculous
6000 Mbps Network Out
```

I have 2 accounts on there:

1. Magento 2.4.2-p1 with about 2200 products
2. New Magento 2.4.5 (same products) which I'm setting up to move all accounts over from the Magento 2.4.2-p1 when ready.

Neither of these have ever been optimized in any way. Every once in a while (about a couple of times a week), the server runs out of memory and ElasticSearch stops working which makes the categories not load (when customers click on them).

Our hosting company is pushing us to upgrade our hosting package. The next one going up is $219.95 / month and it has 32 GB of RAM. This really seems unnecessary?

**Are there alternate solutions I could put in place?** Is it possible to set up the hosting so that when ElasticSearch falls over, it would restart automatically and then the necessary commands would run automatically? Such as:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance improving suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: We would use your data for analysis of each system.  2.4.2-p1 and 2.4.5 if you will post data from each.  If there are requests you do not know how to get the data, ask your hosting company to provide the data for you in TEXT format, please.

Answer (score 0):

They most likely don't lie to you but they obviously don't investigate the root cause. It can be the case that certain services run out of memory and hosters look at this issue as a one-timer. The solution for them is often to increase the ram, which makes kinda sense. If this happens over and over you end up in a situation where you pay more and more.

There is not much more to say here except, debugging, profiling, and finding the root cause.

Have fun

Comment: to be fair, it might be related to the Amasty extensions xD

Answer (score 0):

There is much more you should investigate in your store:

**Possible Problems**

- The issue with the Elasticsearch configuration
- The issue with Speed & caching
- Issue with third-party extension code

**Possible Outcome Solutions**

- Upgrade hosting if your traffic has higher traffic of customers.
- Check Elastic search configuration
- write the Elasticsearch script to run the services if it's down
  suddenly.
- Optimize your store with proper speed optimization
- Analyze the requested data by turning on profiling and checking the
  actual issue

Thanks